# Teradata SQL - hours to number of minutes

Tags: teradata

I have a column with below values and wonder how can I change it to number of minutes.

```
100 is 1 hr 00 min -> 60
200 is 2 hrs 00 min -> 120
```

My column is integer.

Comment: 1000 is 10 hours?  It sure looks like `hours * .6`

Answer (score 0):

If it's always an `INTEGER` in the format of `HHMM` or `HMM`, then you can do this:

```sql
((MyColumn / 100) * 60) + MyColumn MOD 100
```

This will extract the hours and convert it to minutes, extract the minutes and then sum the two together.

[SQL Fiddle (Postgres)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/38009)